# How to use OpenACC for computing the Mandelbrot set?

Tags: c++, openacc

I'm trying to learn to use OpenACC and to begin with I'm implementing it in a simple code for computing the Mandelbrot set but I receive errors when compiling my code.

I found this

[OpenACC must have routine information error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274167/openacc-must-have-routine-information-error)

and thought it would be easy to use in my code but it didn't seem to work.

These are the routines I want to use OpenACC on, and what I tried

```
#pragma acc parallel loop copyout(color)

for (int i=0;i<=n0x;i++)
{

Cx=Re_start+dx*i;

  #pragma acc loop

    for (int h=0;h<=n0y;h++)
    {

    Cy=Im_start+dy*h;
    Zx1=0.;
    Zy1=0.;

    #pragma acc loop

        for(int k=0;k<=n;k++ && mod<=4.)
        { 


        Zx=Zx1*Zx1-Zy1*Zy1+Cx;
        Zy=2*Zx1*Zy1+Cy;
        Zx1=Zx;
        Zy1=Zy; 

        mod=(Zx*Zx+Zy*Zy);

            if(mod<=4.)
            {

            if(k==n) 
            color[i][h]=-1; 


            color[i][h]=k+1;

            }

        }  

    }

}
```

I receive the error (I'm compiling using `pgc++ -acc splot.cpp -Minfo=accel`)

```
PGCC-S-0155-Compiler failed to translate accelerator region (see -Minfo messages): Unknown variable reference (splot.cpp: 48)
main:
     48, Generating copyout(color[:][:])
         Generating Tesla code
         52, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.x */
         59, #pragma acc loop seq
         68, #pragma acc loop vector(128) /* threadIdx.x */
     52, Accelerator restriction: scalar variable live-out from loop: color
     59, Loop is parallelizable
         Accelerator restriction: scalar variable live-out from loop: color
     68, Loop is parallelizable
         Accelerator restriction: scalar variable live-out from loop: color
PGCC-F-0704-Compilation aborted due to previous errors. (splot.cpp)
PGCC/x86-64 Linux 19.4-0: compilation aborted
```

What do I need to modify to be able to compile and run my code properly?

Comment: Can you post a full reproducing example?  I tried, but can't reproduce the error which what you have shown.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'full reproducing example', but I will give you the file and hope it helps. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W8TrW0ovNXwUWljCMf44fKrmPP4KsZiu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm meaning everything needed (including all source, header and input files if required) to reproduce the issue, which this link provides.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "&& mod<=4.0" in " for(int k=0;k<=n;k++ && mod<=4.)".  Compound expressions in for loops is a known PGI limitation and not currently available in device code generation.

Removing the "&& mod<=4.0" will work around the problem.

I can file an issue report, though I'm unclear why this bit of code is there since it seems extraneous.  Can you explain the intent?

Comment: Removing "&& mod<=4.0" (it was there cause I modified my original code so I could use OpenACC and I never removed it) did solve  the compiler error that appeared but the program doesn't run as expected. If I compile using ``g++ -o splot splot.cpp`` and run the program I generate the expected plot, but when compiling using ``pgc++ -acc splot -Minfo=accel`` and running the a.out executable, the program outputs different values for the elements of ``color`` every time I run the program which are far from the correct values. Here is the link to the program and a .dat file that shows what I said.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16MSLtmxA_scGYJKpgfSiTOKe06JjNoaT/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ztwSS4ssZLbZTGLlVd56VNUNtMj2m3Lj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have a race condition.  The "k" loop isn't parallelizable due to the data dependency on "color[i][h]=...".  Either use "pragam acc loop seq" on this loop so it's forced to run sequentially, or simply remove the pragma.